# Managing obtained Instagram hashtag feed (delete photos from grid)

Tags: php, fancybox, feed, instagram, hashtag

I use Instagram API and Fancybox Simplified to get an Instagram hashtag feed. Instructions there: http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

This is PHP code to insert on a web page:

```
<?php
    // Supply a user id and an access token
    $userid = "MY_USER_ID";
    $accessToken = "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 18);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/canon/media/recent?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&count=18");
    $result = json_decode($result);
?>


<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

On the result web page I have undesirable insta photo with certain URL.

How I can remove this item from my grid feed?

Comment: Have a look at the contents of `$result` with `echo "<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";`. Part of it (probably `$result->data`) will be an array, and you can `unset()` elements. If you are still stuck, perhaps edit a sample of that data structure into your question?

Comment: We don't add answers as question updates here, so I've moved your update to another answer. We encourage self-answers here, so next time you solve something yourself, just add your own answer and self-accept.

Answer (score 0):

Append some logic to delete images you don't want. I've used a simple comparison, which removes just one item, but you might apply a list instead:

```
// Pulls and parses data.
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/canon/media/recent?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&count=18");
$result = json_decode($result);

// Delete images according to certain specifications
foreach ($result as $id => $post) {
    if ($post->images->thumbnail->url == 'unwanted_image.jpg') {
        unset($result[$id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how is to set this by the correct way. I tried several variants but have just printing my php code as text right in instagram grid.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7a7timwtcxyvjt/bfw_error.png

Comment: My code was intended to be run inside your existing `<?php ?>` tags (currently lines 1-20), so you would add my section starting `// Delete images...` after your existing `$result = json_decode($result);`. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes. Result on the screenshot.

Comment: But your other PHP _in exactly the same place_ is correctly executed? That should not be possible `:)`. Can you add a http://pastie.org in the comments containing your full script?

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/pl3rjqqhfpvf1ps7iucpeg
I put it in <?php ?>, now i see that this comparing didn't work. Something is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I think I can see what's wrong. But in the meantime you've just published your access token, which I suspect you should treat like a password. I expect Instagram will allow you to regenerate those...

Comment: Try deleting the closing tag `?>` on line 20, and also the opening one `<?php` on line 22 - there's no need to close and then immediately re-open.

Comment: Hmm, to be fair I am not sure that will fix it. But it's good to tidy anyway. Also, I used `$post->images->thumbnail` when it looks like `$post->images->thumbnail->url` is required, but again I don't think that will fix it. But, try anyway!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Here is how I fixed it:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
<?php if ($post->images->thumbnail->url == 'http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/accb25dcbd9c11e3a46812e95f55900b_5.jpg') {
    continue;
    }
?>
<a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```